Amazon SP-APIで注文レポートのbill-nameおよびbill-addressを取得する方法
Amazon SP-APIを使用して、セラーセントラルからダウンロード可能な注文レポートと同等のデータを取得しようとしています。マーケットプレイスは日本です。
現在、GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDER_REPORT_DATA_SHIPPINGを使用して比較的近しいデータを取得できましたが、以下の4つの項目が不足しています。

bill-name
bill-address-1
bill-address-2
bill-address-3

これらの項目を含むデータを取得できるエンドポイントが見つからず困っています。どなたか、これらの情報を取得する方法をご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授いただけますと幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。
